# Post Map simulation reliability

Tags: fpga, vhdl, simulation

I'm designing a module in VHDL for an FPGA. My module is added to already existing design. It has a Wishbone slave interface. The IDE (Lattice Semiconductor Diamond 3.2  ) allows to do post map simulation, so I simulated only my modulebecause it's too complicated and slow to simulate from the top module. The problem is I have different behaviour between real implementation ( the entire design ) and post map simulated module (the simulation of my design ) . RTL simulation and post map simulation have same behaviour. I know that it could be a timing fault, but I don't get any error from the P&R tool and every nets follow the clock.

Now I'm pretty sure about the rightness of my design but I'm not sure about the Wishbone compliant of the others module in the design. Could the post map simulation be a proof of the rightness of my vhdl code ?

Answer (score 2):

> Could the post map simulation be a proof of the rightness of my vhdl code ?

No. Especially if you are just "looking at the waveforms."

**If** you have an independently created testbench which will tell you pass and fail information, then you can use that in simulation with either your RTL or post-map to provide evidence of correctness (but only for the parts that are actively tested, very rarely is a testbench absolutely all encompassing of all corner cases on any complex piece of logic).

However, if you have written your own testbench, you are likely to test the same interpretation of the spec that you used to write your RTL code, and therefore will find that you ass (and that others may also fail).  That doesn't mean *your* code is correct :)

(A comment on "engineering humility": I've no idea how experienced you are, but speaking as an engineer of 20+ years experience (almost) every time I think "those other people got it wrong" I find that I have misunderstood some detail of the specification.  It's very rare that the problem is in the tools, or the simulator, or the implementation that has been in use for years by many other engineers :)

Comment: You were right, the problem was in the test of hardware. The design was correct the problem was the input that I provided to the FPGA.  Not all my code was correct. I was so focused about VHDL that I didn't focus on the testing code. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Comment: Yes, the testing code is an integral part of the "design" :)